# Calculate when value change to the table

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Hello i want to automatically calculate the grades when the value of the table change and put the total to grade. Can someone give me ideas how to do this? I don't know any of the events and i don't know how to use ajax. Can someone help me about this? I'm just starting to learn it.

Here some picture 
[image]

my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Student Portal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href ="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="img/png" href="img/gapclogo.png"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    .table-bordered{
        width: auto !important;
        margin-top: 200px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


    <table class="table table-bordered" align="center" >

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="300">Name</th>
                <th width="100">Long Quiz 20%</th>
                <th width="100">Attendance 10%</th>
                <th width="100">Homework/Seatwork 20%</th>
                <th width="100">Recitation 10%</th>
                <th width="100">Major Exam 40%</th>
                <th width="100">Grade</th>
                <th width="100">Equivalent</th>
                 <th width="100">Remarks</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td contenteditable="true" onchange="Calculate();" id="quiz"></td>
                <td contenteditable="true" onchange="Calculate();" id="atten"></td>
                <td contenteditable="true" onchange="Calculate();" id="home"></td>
                <td contenteditable="true" onchange="Calculate();" id="reci"></td>
                <td contenteditable="true" onchange="Calculate();" id="me"></td>
                <td ></td>
                <td ></td>
                <td ></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>


    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function Calculate()
    {
       quiz = document.getElementById('quiz');
        attend = document.getElementById('atten');
         home = document.getElementById('home');
        reci = document.getElementById('reci');
         me = document.getElementById('me');

         q = quiz.value / 100 * 50 + 50;
         a = atten.value / 100 * 50 + 50;
         h = home.value / 100 * 50 + 50;
         r = reci.value / 100 * 50 + 50;
         m = me.value / 100 * 50 + 50;

         qt = q * 0.2;
         at = a * 0.1;
         ht = h * 0.2;
         rt = r * 0.1;
         mt = m * 0.4;

         grade = qt + at + ht + rt + mt;
      }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you editing the table directly or is the table being edited else where are you're effectively wanting to listen for changes and update accordingly?

Comment: @Connor Im editing the table directly. The table is editable.

Comment: @nethken If you're using `contenteditable` do `document.querySelectorAll("td[contenteditable']");' loop through them and attach a `blur` event listener which will be fired when you unfocus the td after editing.

Comment: @nethken Here's an example of how you can listen for changes. https://jsfiddle.net/ahcv17kd/

Comment: @Connor hi sir can you look again at my code? i want to put the grade total to grade column.

Comment: Give your "grade" column an id, and then use jquery to set the value.  `$('#grade_td_id_goes_here').html(grade);`

Comment: @BrandonHorsley Why it's not working? The grade column is blank nothing happens :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First two changes : give an "id" to the `<td>` where you want to display the result, and replace the "onchange" event by "onkeydown" :

```
    <tr>
        <td></td>                       ▼
        <td contenteditable="true" onkeydown="Calculate();" id="quiz"></td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onkeydown="Calculate();" id="atten"></td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onkeydown="Calculate();" id="home"></td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onkeydown="Calculate();" id="reci"></td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onkeydown="Calculate();" id="me"></td>
        <td id="td_grade"></td>  ◄■■■■
        <td ></td>
        <td ></td>
    </tr>
```

Now let's change your "Calculate" function : you are editing `<td>` tags, so you have to use "innerHTML" instead of "value", and store the result in the "td_grade" :

```
function Calculate()
{
   quiz = document.getElementById('quiz');
    attend = document.getElementById('atten');
     home = document.getElementById('home');
    reci = document.getElementById('reci');
     me = document.getElementById('me');

 q = quiz.innerHTML / 100 * 50 + 50;      ◄■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
 a = atten.innerHTML / 100 * 50 + 50;     ◄■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
 h = home.innerHTML / 100 * 50 + 50;      ◄■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
 r = reci.innerHTML / 100 * 50 + 50;      ◄■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
 m = me.innerHTML / 100 * 50 + 50;        ◄■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■

 qt = q * 0.2;
 at = a * 0.1;
 ht = h * 0.2;
 rt = r * 0.1;
 mt = m * 0.4;

 grade = qt + at + ht + rt + mt;
 document.getElementById('td_grade').innerHTML = grade;       ◄■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
```

}